# Datatables(2.1.4) How to use aButtons to change the csv content

Tags: javascript, csv, datatables

In my table , there is a column value is **"google"** and when user click it , it will be a link to google website. But when user want to export the **csv content** , I want to change the google value as a link instead . For now , the csv content is just google text.

**How to do it in my Buttons feature ?**

**my code :**

```
"oTableTools": {
      "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
      "aButtons": [
          {
            "sExtends": "csv",
            "sButtonText": "export csv",
          }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added fnCellRender function into aButtons like below to make some changes to the csv content.

```
{
      "sExtends": "csv",
      "sButtonText": "export CSV",
      "sCharSet": "utf8",//solve csv chinese encoded problem
      "bBomInc": true,//solve csv chinese encoded problem
      "fnCellRender": function ( sValue, iColumn, nTr, iDataIndex ) {
               if(sValue.toString().match("href")){
                        return $(sValue).attr("href");
               }
               return sValue;
      }//to make some change to the cell content before export the csv
}
```